# Custom Email Message (Salesforce)

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud

I have created a flow that sends emails (action) and creates an email message for these sent emails.

Everything works fine, except for the email responses to my email message. I was searching the EmailMessage SObject and I noticed that I need to populate the "ThreadId" field in EmailMessage.

I created a formula to populate the new ThreadId (updated the format in Winter '24), but it still isn't working. I don't receive any responses.

If I send the email from Salesforce (native component), it works fine. However, if I create an email message from the flow and email alert, the responses do not show up.

I created a formula to populate the new ThreadId (updated the format in Winter '24), but it still isn't working. I don't receive any responses.